# PHP Loops and Arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays, loops

How can I list all array items except that there is another Array ?
Example:

First array:

```
$idea_id[$row["id"]] = $row["id"];
```

Second array:

```
$m_voted[$votedke] = $row["ideaid"];
```

Keeping this datas in separate SQL tables.
And how to list all `$idea_id` but if

```
$idea_id[this_item] == $m_voted[any_item]
```

then `this item` not listing.

Answer (score 0):

From your question what i understand is you want to check the data exists in the second array.

You can use `in_array` function which check if the **idea_id** is in **m_voted** array

```
foreach($idea_id as $id){
   if(in_array($id,$m_voted)){
       echo "{$id}<br/>";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.

Comment: Didn't worked with inArray. I changed in_array and worked but getting a plus error message. -> Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in.

Comment: As from your question `$m_voted` is an array but its not thats why its howing error this error. This can be because the `$m_voted` is not set so make `$m_voted = []` at the start of your code. It's a guess please update the code in your question. So i can be more clear